# Unable to place images in the desired way in grid view

Tags: android

I want to know how can I make a layout like the attached one.

Through grid layout I am able to achieve almost what I want but the images are not getting placed in this manner, please suggest what could be done in this case.
Shall I use some other view or what?

[image: goal]

Comment: You're going to need a custom layout.  Although you may be able to do it with a RecyclerView and a customized LayoutManager.  GridView isn't really made to do offsets like that, it does grids.

Comment: ok @GabeSechan, I will try that, ty for the time .